# Is there a sample sms database out there for development or research use?

Tags: sms

I am currently working on a personal project that involves data mining SMS messages.  The problem is that I am at the point where I want to be working with realistic data besides my own SMS messages, and need about a years worth of history.

I do not feel comfortable asking acquaintances for this data because of how deeply personal it can be.

I am wondering if there is already a data set out there that I can use for these purposes, either free or for purchase.

Comment: Download a load of tweets? http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/13732/download-all-the-tweets-from-a-twitter-user

Comment: It's not quite the same use case, since what I'm really interested in are conversations.